# Cron won't run my root script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, cron

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 (using Digital Ocean) trying run a script as root. It's a script to check if a server is running and restart if it has crashed.

The issue isn't the script, but crontab won't run the script.

`sudo crontab -e`

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/launch.sh
#newline
```

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 845 Nov 23 06:21 launch.sh`

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, other posts about crontabs have shown similar answers to this one.

Comment: The syntax for `root`'s `crontab` is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem.

I added my bash commands to `/etc/crontab` and added the `root` field instead of using `sudo crontab -e`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*  *    * * *   root    bash /root/launch.sh
```